# MVC 4 WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken does not work when table is replicated in sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security

I receive a

`"Database operation failed"`

exception every time I run the function `WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken`.

I have traced this back to the fact that all my webpages_ tables are replicated and replication adds an extra field invalidating the `Membership` model.

Is there a way to make this work on a replicated table?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "replicated"?  Do you mean that these tables have been replicated?  As in, they are the copies?  Or that they are the source tables?  What kind of replication are you using?

Comment: I mean that mssql has replication configured on these tables

Comment: Yes, and again.. What kind of replication are you using, there are 4 different kinds.  And are they the source or the destination tables?

Comment: it is a source table, and the type is transactional

Comment: It is failing because SQL Replication will add a column to your schema, therefore your schema no longer matches your model.

Comment: @Barry that is exactly what is happening.

Comment: Is there any way to work-around this?

Comment: **1** way is obvious: remove the table from replication (I know thats not ideal). **2** Another approach, Simple Membership uses EF. Try to map EF's CRUD for that table to your own stored procs **3** Final way is to implement your own SimpleMembershipProvider class. `Good Luck, I know this isn't gona be fun or easy`

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if it helps to add the extra columns in your table, to the EF definition which was auto-created in the C# program. The EF operations should then operate correctly behind the scenes. Here's how to add them:

In the `UserProfile` class, in `AccountModels.cs` program, add the column(s) as follows:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    // Customization: Field(s) added
    public string AddedFieldName { get; set; }
}
```

I have successfully used this technique to add custom columns (such as registered users' names and other info) to the SimpleMembership system, and have in fact written a set of [blog articles](http://www.dwdmbi.com/2012/10/adding-custom-fields-to-vs2012-mvc4.html) about it, which may be of some further help in this context.